# How to preserve aspect ratio of img elements within ul, li tags?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When a user is on his/her phone, the images gets distorted, the width changes, but the height doesn't.

I'm not sure exactly what I should change, I tried adding a max-height but that doesn't seem to work as I'd thought it would.

I want to also point out that I'm using CSS Bootstrap.

```
<ul style="position: absolute; max-width: 625px; list-style-type: none; margin: 0 auto;" class="username">';
  <li style="list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <img style="height: 360px" class="img-thumbnail" src="filename" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are only defining the height, try changing it to:

```
<ul style="position: absolute; max-width: 625px; list-style-type: none; margin: 0 auto;" class="username">';
  <li style="list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <img style="height: 360px; width: 360px (or however wide your image is)" class="img-thumbnail" src="filename">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also self-closing tags are no longer valid in HTML5, so I removed that too

Comment: Yup tried that. It still gets distorted. Also, I forgot to mention that I'm using CSS Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

just change one dimension and set the other to auto, like:

```
width:150px;
height:auto;
```

Comment: It still gets distorted. Also, I forgot to mention that I'm using CSS Bootstrap.